# Does Django save model objects other than `save()` or `create()` methods?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing something like the following:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField()

def f(foo: Foo) -> Foo:
    y = Foo(
        **{field.name: getattr(foo, field.name) for field in foo._meta.get_fields()}
    )  # copy foo with pk
    y.a = "c"
    return y
```

My concern is whether `y` are saved to DB before users call `save()` method. Could it occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not saved. You need to actually call `y.save()` for the updated fields to be persisted to the DB.

In this case, you can make the `save` more efficient by [specifying fields which actually changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#ref-models-update-fields):

```
y.save(update_fields=['a'])
```

Answer (score 0):

No, y instance won't be saved to DB before users call save() method. If you want to save the new instance y to the database, you need to call y.save().